# Neuigkeit vs Nachricht

Tags: usage

While conversing with 2 native German speakers I said,

> Wir haben **Nachricht**, euch zu erzählen! Carolina ist schwanger!

They corrected me to

> Wir haben **Neuigkeit**, euch zu erzählen! Carolina ist schwanger!

but could not tell me why. Is there an explanation?

Comment: For me, a common word order could be 'Wir haben euch Neuigkeiten zu erzählen.' A sentence with 'Nachricht' could be: 'Wir haben eine gute Nachricht: Carolina ist schwanger' or 'Es gibt eine gute Nachricht / Es gibt gute Nachrichten: ...'  'Wir haben euch eine Nachricht zu erzählen' sounds strange: A 'Nachricht' is supposed to be shared ('weitergegeben') or communicated ('mitgeteilt'), but never 'erzählt' like a story, as far as I can judge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nachrichten** and **Neuigkeiten** (along with **Informationen**) have different informal meanings compared with the general *news*.

There is a cultural context hidden underneath which makes referencing this very hard.
So from a German native speaker let me explain my understanding:

**Nachrichten**

Stating facts that happened. Kind of neutral meaning and in this context is used mainly for news reporting on radio and TV.
Like reporting on a state of affairs, things happening in towns.

**Neuigkeiten**

This word is taken with an informal positive meaning. As in something nice happened or is happening.

**Informationen**

In a way anything that is happening or has a negative or neutral meaning becomes simply information. Also the use of this term can reflect on the current state of ongoing affairs which are not resolved yet.

In your context the fact that a woman is pregnant ticks to me these boxes:

- happy news
- ongoing

The use of the word **Neuigkeiten** as an introduction to the actual news is therefore "expected".

Comment: `"This word is taken with an informal positive meaning."` I wouldn't agree. There are "gute" und "schlechte" Neuigkeiten. "Ich habe Neuigkeiten" is (at least for me) neither positive nor negative

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you meant "Nachricht" in the sense of news (and not in the sense of message/communication).

> "I have **news**! Carolina is pregnant"

> I have a message for you.

Both variants are possible, but "Neuigkeit" is used much more often in this context.

> Wir haben eine **Nachricht** für euch: "RDBury ist schwanger!"

> Wir haben **Neuigkeiten**: "XYZ ist schwanger!"

The word is ambiguous, as it can also mean "message with new information".

(I think this could have been found in a dictionary/translator. Maybe you can explain the difficulties you had during your research process.)

[Nachricht](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/nachricht) [Nachricht](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nachricht) [Nachricht](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/nachricht)

[Neuigkeit](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/neuigkeit) [Neuigkeit](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Neuigkeit) [Neuigkeit](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/neuigkeit)

Comment: Ich dachte, nur XX kann schwanger werden. Dass XY schwanger ist, ist echt erstaunlich.

Comment: *Nachricht in the sense of news* lacks precision given the numerous meanings of [news](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/news). At least one counter-example (which kind of "Nachricht" is excluded) would be helpful.

Comment: @guidot I thought about that too, but i wasn't sure, if there is any *real* difference. Aren't news actually always "messages with new information"?

Comment: @guidot I misunderstood. I edited the post..

Answer (score 0):

**Nachricht** is like a general news.
**Neuigkeiten** is when you are referring to specific piece of news.

- Good Day folks! Today we will broadcast the news at 7 PM.
- Honey! I have an exciting news for you. Will tell you at 7 PM.